# ElasticSearch: Aggregation with order by top_hits differs in doc count

Tags: json, elasticsearch, indexing, aggregate

My problem is that having a max score aggregation that sorts by _score, in combination with a terms aggregation, is showing a different doc_count.

Here is the aggregation block that I want, but giving a lower doc_count for certain results. Again, it always gives a *lower* value; never higher.

```
"aggs": {
  "group_by_field": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "field4",
      "order": {
        "max_score": "desc"
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "max_score": {
        "max": {
          "script": "_score"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the aggregation block that I do not want, but is showing the correct doc_count for all results.

```
"aggs": {
  "group_by_target": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "target"
    }
  }
}
```

For those interested, here is my full body query:

```
{
    "index": "myIndex",
    "type": "myType",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": {
                    0: {
                        "term": {
                            "term1": false,
                        }
                    }
                },
                "must": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": {
                            0: {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    "phrase1": "example",
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "minimum_should_match": 1,
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "size": 0,
        "_source": {
            0: "field1",
            1: "field2",
            2: "field3",
            3: "field4",
        },
        "aggs": {
            "group_by_field": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "field4",
                    "size": 25,
                    "order": {
                        "max_score": "desc",
                    }
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "max_score": {
                        "max": {
                            "script": "_score",
                        }
                    },
                    "my_top_agg": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "size": 3,
                            "_source": {
                                0: "field1",
                                1: "field2",
                                2: "field3",
                                3: "field4",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "my_total": {
                "cardinality": {
                    "field": "field4",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have test both queries and each time it is showing a the same incorrect doc_count when having the order aggregation. What is causing the problem?

Comment: I thinck your first aggregation return only the top (10 default size) elements to your second one. Could you test with a higher value?

Comment: @LeBigCat Are you referring to the max_score aggregation? Should I add the size property as a sibling of script?

Comment: I thinck you should try, when you encapsulate severals aggs, only the doc on the master agg are analysed in the childs, so if you make some operations after to merge back fields you wont have all docs.

Comment: @LeBigCat Unfortunately, that is not the issue. My problem is that the returned doc_count for every aggregation under group_by_field is sometimes less than it should be. For instance: For some results it returns 2300, which is correct, but sometimes it returns 2, while it should be 6. Removing the extra max_score aggregation fixes this issue, but now the main results are no longer sorted by their _score. Is that making sense?

Comment: Ok my bad. Sorry for the mis-understanding.

Comment: @LeBigCat No problem, thanks for your help! If you have other suggestion let me know.